# How to subtract 13 weeks from a date in PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date in sql which will always fall on a Monday and I'm subtracting 13 weeks to get a weekly report. I am trying to get the same 13 week report but for last year's figures as well.

At the moment, I'm using the following:

```
calendar_date >=  TRUNC(sysdate) - 91
```

which is working fine.

I need the same for last year.

However, when I split this into calendar weeks, there will also be a partially complete week as it will include 1 or 2 days from the previous week. I need only whole weeks.

e.g. the dates that will be returned for last year will be 14-Feb-2015 to 16-May-2015. I need it to start on the Monday and be 16-Feb-2015. This will change each week as I am only interested in complete weeks...

Comment: Well you could just subtract 52 weeks, which would always give you the Monday still. But you may need to correct for the extra week in the year: if your company works in 13-week blocks what's their logic for dealing with the extra week - occasionally use 14 weeks over Christmas?

Comment: Why did you edit the code to be exactly the same? Also, trunc isn't used in SQL server, so I'd say that it's PL SQL.

Thanks for the answer, will try doing weeks instead..

Comment: The original version wasn't formatted as code, although it was fairly clear as-was too. You can use the 'edit' link above ti put the tag back or roll-back the change entirely. (You also probably had to @ him to get his attention - it directed this at me as it guessed you were replying to my comment.)

Comment: Ah right, sorry about that. I wasn't looking for another answer from him so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

- Get the date by substracting 91 days as you're already doing.
- Get the number of the day of the week with `TO_CHAR(DATE,'d')`
- Add the number of days until the next monday to the date.

Something like this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_DATE('16/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')-91 + MOD(7 - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE('16/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/RRRR')-91,'d'))+1,7) d
FROM dual
```

Comment: One caveat: his example is the Monday after date minus 91: he wanted the 16th Feb not 14th Feb.

Comment: You're right! I didn't read that part. I changed my answer so that it returns the next monday instead of the previous monday to the date. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

next_day - returns date of first weekday named by char.

```
with dates as (select to_date('16/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') d from dual)
  select 
       trunc(next_day( trunc(d-91) - interval '1' second,'MONDAY'))
  from dates;
```

I want to get next monday from calculated date. In situation when calculated date is monday i have to move back to previous week ( -1 second).